# Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503 in ISTIO

Tags: azure, kubernetes, istio, azure-aks

I have deployed istio service mesh in my AKS cluster. i have ui and backend services both configured in istio for service communication. i am able to invoke backend service through istio, and no problem in accessing my backend services.

But i am facing issue in test-ui pod, when i see pod status

```
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
Test-api-deployment-59f6c6f67-ml4xm   2/2     Running   0          3d21h
Test-ui-deployment-b54fd89b-2ndsv     1/2     Running   0          52m
```

In above status, my ui pod , one of my istio container is not in ready state to serve my request.. when i looked into the container state, i get below error..

```
Warning  Unhealthy  2m24s (x299 over 12m)  kubelet, aks-wmsdevk8s-25812762-4  
Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

i see it an open issue [issue in github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/12446).. is there any workaround for this...

EDIT

my istio version

> version.BuildInfo{Version:"1.1.5",
>   GitRevision:"9b6d31b74d1c0cc9358cc82d395b53f71393326b", User:"root",
>   Host:"3e29fde4-6c3f-11e9-b00d-0a580a2c0205", GolangVersion:"go1.10.4",
>   DockerHub:"docker.io/istio", BuildStatus:"Clean",
>   GitTag:"1.1.4-10-g9b6d31b"}

```
istio proxy version -   Image:         docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.1.2
```

Comment: whats your istio version?

Comment: build version is "1.1.5"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work with istio 1.1.5. I suppose you didnt configure istio to rewrite HTTPProbes. You need to install Istio with the `sidecarInjectorWebhook.rewriteAppHTTPProbe=true` ([source](https://preliminary.istio.io/help/ops/setup/app-health-check/#configure-istio-to-rewrite-liveness-http-probes)).

You can check your `istio-sidecar-injector` configmap, it should have `rewriteAppHTTPProbe: true`

ps. it works for me with istio 1.1.2, i believe

Comment: i checked my config map. it is false rewriteAppHTTPProbe: false. do i need to change to true? to make it work?

Comment: yes, change it to true and delete the pod. it should recreate the sidecar with new config values

Comment: i have changed to rewriteAppHTTPProbe: true, still getting the same error , i think i need to increase global.proxy.readinessInitialDelaySeconds to higher value.. as said in this post https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/12653

Comment: you could try that as well, it works without that value for me

Comment: above update will automatically propagate to my pod services config... or do i need to apply for each pod services?..

Comment: changes to configmap istio-sidecar-injector propaget to all sidecars. you'd need to restart all sidecars though

Comment: issue is still exists.. this answer not solved the issue.. i am trying this solution https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/12653

Comment: this is a completely different issue, for which you raised a new question. this question is answered

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tested on OpenShift 3.11 with ServiceMesh TP 0.10 and used ovs-multitenant(SDN plugin) so inter-projects communications were blocked. I had same problem and set netid of istio-system namespace to "0", then problem was solved.
Check network communications between your application's namespace and namespace which has istio-sidecar-injector.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your sidecar proxy and rewrite the app probe endpoint using istioctl

`kb get <deployment/statefulset> -n <namespace> <resource_name>  -o yaml | istioctl kube-inject --rewriteAppProbe -f - | kubectl apply -f -`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable liveness probe for pods:

If you already installed `Istio`, you can change config map in namespace `istio-system`

```
kubectl get cm istio-sidecar-injector -n istio-system -o yaml | \ 
sed -e 's/rewriteAppHTTPProbe:false/rewriteAppHTTPProbe:true/' | \
kubectl apply -f -
```

If you are going to install `Istio`, you can enable it globally using `istioctl`

```
istioctl manifest apply --set values.sidecarInjectorWebhook.rewriteAppHTTPProbe=true
```

If you want to enable HTTP probe for specific deployment or pod without globally affecting on other installed resources, simple annotate pod with `sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"`. in case you want to customize probe section, take a look at the following example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: liveness-http
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: liveness-http
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: liveness-http
        version: v1
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: liveness-http
        image: docker.io/istio/health:example
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8001
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /foo
            port: 8001
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
```

For more information about Health Checking of Istio Services, check out their [documentation here](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/ops/configuration/mesh/app-health-check/#configure-istio-to-rewrite-liveness-http-probes).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue on OKD 3.11 with Istio 1.1.2. After setting netid of istio-system namespace to "0", then problem was solved.

Check netid :

```
oc get netnamespaces
```

Set netid to "0" :

```
oc adm pod-network make-projects-global istio-system
```